# How replace join query with whereHas?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6 and i have a standard query

```
    Order::where('dict_statuses_id', 1)
->leftJoin('dict_statuses', 'dict_statuses_id', '=', 'dict_statuses.id')
->get();
```

So i have list of orders with details where status = 1 (new) after join table i see status as New or Complete. Is any way to change this query using whereHas ?

i tried use

```
Order::whereHas('status', function($q){
            $q->where('dict_statuses_id', 1);
        })->get();
```

But no results, in model Order i have

```
public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\DictStatuses');
    }
```

[Updated]

i have an error:

```
  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dict_statuses.orders_id' 
in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where exists 
(select * from `dict_statuses` where `orders`.`id` = `dict_statuses`.`orders_id` and `dict_statuses_id` = 1) 
and `orders`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

In my table i have table **Orders** where is field: **dict_statuses_id**
and table **dict_statuses** with fields: **id**, **public_name**

Why error is about **dict_statuses.orders_id**

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in variables to a relationship so you could potentially do.

```
public function status($id) {
    return $this->hasMany(DictStatuses::class)->where('dict_statuses_id', $id);
}
```

Try defining the local key & foreign key.

```
$this->hasMany(DictStatuses::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Comment: What table is 'dict_statuses_id' on?

Comment: This is a key to table dict_statuses

Comment: Have you tried manually defining the local & foreign key in the relationship?

Comment: Ok i have in orders table: CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`dict_statuses_id`) REFERENCES `dict_statuses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE . is that ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Order::has('status')->get();

Answer (score 0):

I think your `dict_statuses` doesn't have a column called order_id.

Please include that column in your migration

then call

```
Order::whereHas('status', function($q){
        $q->where('dict_statuses_id', 1);
    })->get();
```

in your controller

or change the relation in Order model as

```
public function status(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\DictStatuses'):
}
```